# openjpa-maven-plugin does not enhance entity classes at buildtime

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

I got another Problem with OpenJPA.
It seems like my Entities didnt get enhanced even though I inserted the openjpa-maven-plugin in my pom.xml.

Here the error code:

```
<openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "
al.das.MyProject.Entities.Entity1
al.das.MyProject.Entities.Entity2
al.das.MyProject.Entities.Entity3".
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>al.das</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>MyProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId> 
      <version>1.16.16</version> 
      <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
      <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>al/das/MyProject/Entities/*.class</includes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I first thought I probably registered the wrong path to my entity classes in the plugin section, but no alternative approach I came up with did work.

Do I need to specify the path to my class files in my workspace folder or in the directory structure of my tomcat?

**In tomcat the path is:** 
wtpwebapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/classes/al/das/MyProject/Entities

**In my Workspace:** 
MyProject/target/classes/al/das/MyProject/Entities

Just to be safe here my current persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MyProject">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>al.das.MyProject.Entities.Entity1</class>
        <class>al.das.MyProject.Entities.Entity2</class>
        <class>al.das.MyProject.Entities.Entity3</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults" value="ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="user"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="password"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No, sadly I didnt. Only solutions I got to work was enhancing at runtime with javaagent or skipping enhancement entirely.

Comment: FYI, I ended up finding the issue.  The Open JPA enhancer was failing on a compile error but not reporting why it failed.

Comment: @MrSmith Having similiar issue, wanna look at that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66471893/how-to-enhance-classes-properly-at-build-time-using-maven-openjpa

Comment: @Wortig - FYI, I have a new job & they don't use OpenJPA here.  If I remember correctly I think I tracked down my issue by the log level for Open JPA to debug & then it listed enough info.